# ASP.NET textbox control not updating from a DLL event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating an asp web site in ms visual studio that will provide CTI functionality from a DLL I developed. Everything works just fine except from an asp textbox.text property which does not update. The property is updated inside the code that handles a DLL event. Currently the textbox is inside an "UpdatePanel" container. My code doesn't initialize or change textbox's property anywhere.

part of asp auto generated code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Height="50px" 
        style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="913px">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

part of vb.NET code:

```
'DLL declaration
Protected WithEvents oPbxApiNet As PbxApiNet

'code that tries to update textbox (doesn't work)
Protected Sub oPbxApiNet_AgentLoggedIn(extension As String) Handles PbxApiNet.AgentLoggedIn
    txtMsg.Text = "Extension: " & extension & " logged" & vbCrLf & txtMsg.Text
    UpdatePanel.Update()
End Sub
```

Note: Initially I didn't use an "UpdatePanel" but I had the same problem. I added asp buttons that update textbox's property and worked fine. The problem remains only when updated from the event handler code. The DLL was developed using vb.NET.

Comment: Your code is running on the server, so you need to store the value in a session variable, force the page to reload somehow and then populate the textbox from the session variable in Page_load

Comment: Thanks. I stored the value in session. I created a timer that updates the textbox property from the value in session, and it works.